# Test Scenario's on Coding Framework Stories?

Tags: agile-testing, test-planning, user-stories

So I have a quick question: In our "stories" usually at the starting sprints, a lot of the cards are related to how things are going to be coded (classes and such).

Does it make sense to make test scenario's based off of these? Understandably I won't be making acceptance tests (UATP's) off of these types, but I am wondering if it makes sense to write test plans/scenario's "in general" on cards like this.

On one hand, I am not sure how the end "visual/UI" will look like so I feel like my scenario will be written pre-maturely but, on the other hand, it does let me get a head start on test plans.

Comment: In general I would expect that a story contains user's desiderata and not conding details. Could you add more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how you write your test plans.

In that specific case, you can at least do preparatory work, with structure, without details, like

"create a customer, enter an invalid age, checke there is an error message, enter a valid age, check the creation works". If you happen to need more detail in your test plan(really depends on the shop), detail can arrive later.

Of course, this works for pass-through testing. For static testing(Let's take that field in that screen, and make it suffer as much as we can), you can't forecast anything yet.

EDIT after comment :

Then all you have is the underlying structure of your test strategy. It's a starting point, but not much more. Still, with some imagination, you can already prepare a few cases : the "invalide age" case is something I've never seen written in a spec, no matter what form it takes. Still, it should be coded & tested.

I say underlying strategy as you'll have to go through everything to make a full test : every screen, every test case, but also every technical component. It's not common to begin a functional test from there, but as it's your only starting point, if I understand correctly...

Comment: The stories are even less detailed than that, it's more like creating data models and classes that will handle X or Y feature.